# Using view elements inside thread

Tags: android, multithreading, httprequest

I'm trying to do a simple HTTP request in Android. It has to be in separate theread. But how can I operate on the view controls inside the thread?

Here's what I have now:

```
public void saveData(final View v)
{
    Button btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setText("Saving...");

    new Thread() {
        public void run()
        {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {                   
                URL myUrl = new URL("http://example.com");
                connection = (HttpURLConnection)myUrl.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                final String fResponse = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);

            }
            catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                Log.e("aaa", "Invalid URL", ex);
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e("aaa", "IO Exception", ex);
            }
            finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }

           // How can I access v and btn here?     
           // btn.getText("Saved, thanks.");
           // btn.setText("Saved, thanks.");

        }

    }.start();
}
```

To elaborate what I'm trying to achieve:

I have a text box and a button. Once the button is clicked, I want to get the text from text box, use in the URL, wich returns a value, then update the button text with this value.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to access your Views directly from another thread like that, you will get an exception because all UI operations must be performed on the main thread.

One method that the Android SDK provides for performing background tasks that need to update the UI is the [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

The `onPostExecute()` method of an `AsyncTask` is called after `doInBackground()` returns, and is run on the UI thread.

Your AsyncTask might look something like this:

```
public class MyBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        URL myUrl = new URL("http://example.com");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)myUrl.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

        return IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Call back to your Activity with the result here
    }
}
```

Comment: AsyncTask is not THE standard method. It's one of the many options you have, and it is a class that encapsulates threading functionality.  Sometimes it's much easier to use a Runnable() or a Thread() object.

Comment: They certainly aren't the only option, but they provide all of the functionality that you create below for free. There are definitely cases in which you need to create your own Runnable (or in which in will be shorter), but AsyncTasks were created for situations like this. Not to mention that the AsyncTask I created above is only 13 lines of code, which really isn't much.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on how you could do it.

```
public class YourClass extends Activity {
    private Button myButton;
    //create an handler
    private final Handler myHandler = new Handler();

    final Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //call the activity method that updates the UI
            updateUI();
        }
    };
    private void updateUI()
    {
      // ... update the UI     
    }

    private void doSomeHardWork()
    {
         //update the UI using the handler and the runnable
         myHandler.post(updateRunnable);
    }

    private OnClickListener buttonListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                  doSomeHardWork();
            }).start();
        }
    };
}
```

As you can see, you need to update the UI with yet another Runnable object. This is one way of doing it.

Another option is via the `runOnUiThread` function

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateActivity();
    }
});
```